# Copy file from any given path in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, copy

I want to copy a file from outside the root directory of my Laravel application using an artisan command which i made myself. The user will call the command like so:

```
php artisan crawl:pdf {filepath}
```

Then the filepath will be processed and on this part:

```
File::copy($path, storage_path('pdfs') . '/' . $fileName . ".pdf");
```

it breaks every time i use a path outside of my root directory it says "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory" as error msg".

I've already googled about copying files in plain php using copy() and in Laravel using Storage::copy(). Also reading through articles that all describe creating a disk which can route outside of laravel-root-directory.

All of that is not the solution to my problem. The user should be able to use any path.

```
C:\dir1\pdf3.pdf ; 
E:\dir456\pdf2222.pdf`
...
```

from his own filesystem to copy files to the laravel-application.

Is their a way todo it ? Thx for all the help in advance!

EDIT 1:
Before anyone asks if i have write and read permission: yes i do. if i use plain php i can write and read everywhere on my working drive. I also checked the user laravel is running on with echo `whoami` and it gives the same user as my plain php application which works fine.

EDIT 2:
Worked in comments regarding using [File-Facad-copy](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/File.html#method_copy)

Comment: Use the `File` facade to interact with all of the filesystem. `Storage` only interacts with the storage locations defined in `config/filesystems.php`

Comment: ok i changed the code to ´File::copy($test, storage_path('pdfs') . '/' . $fileName . ".pdf");´ but still the same error like before. Failed to open stream: No such file or directory. i double checked the location of my file and even moved it to somewhere else with a shorter path but still same error.

Comment: Does the directory `storage_path('pdfs')` exist?

Comment: yes it does. the $target part of `File::copy(string $path, string $target)` is not the problem. It crashes on the $path part, the origin, if the origin is outside of the laravel-application folder. for example: `C:\Project\laravel-app\somefiles\... .pdf` works. But `C:\testdir\... .pdf` does not

Comment: after some more working on the problem i got a new error code which is more specific `Create a symlink to the target file or directory. On Windows, a hard link is created if the target is a file.` it looks like laravel is expecting a preconfigured link but i dont understand how i can make a preconfigured "empty" link which then gets filled if the user pushes the path to the file that should be uploaded.

Comment: what i dont understand is why laravel is expecting that the link is either somewhere inside the laravel application... is this a restriction by laravel itself ?

Comment: Ok personally I never had such restrictions, however I always use Linux so maybe this is just a windows restriction.  Coincidentally I found that text as a comment [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/89e43ae6be9f173233e89a2f452f8a0c43f0e857/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L323) so that is likely just showing you part of the source code that is failing because the comment is right below the `copy` method.  Speaking of which, you can see there that `File::copy` is literally a shortcut for PHPs internal `copy` so if one works the other should too

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a solution and now it is working as i want it.

But first why is this happening. Laravel is expecting to always work on files using disks. It is required.

the solution is [On-demand Disks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#on-demand-disks)!!!

This way it is possible to take a path given by a user and create a temporary disk which only works in this instance through facades.

Important is to make sure that the path given is always a directory! Like so:

```
$diskpath = dirname($path);
$disk = Storage::build([
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => "$diskpath",
]);
```

In my case I only want to copy one specific file which makes it mandatory to get the file information for correct naming and copying. Like so:

```
$pathinf = pathinfo($path)
$fileName = time() . '_' . $pathinf['filename']
```

Next we need to safe it to the new location. Like so:

```
Storage::disk('pdfs')->putFileAs('/', $path, $fileName . ".pdf");
```

Notes:

- 'pdfs' disk is a disk i configured in my filesystems.php config-file
- I always asume that the user is giving the full path from the file like `C:\...\test.pdf` or something similar so watch out for the [`dirname()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.dirname.php) function. It will always cut the last part of the path and delete it.

Thanks to [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) for helping solving this through his comments and hints.